# Update cart-totals after checking a checkbox (woocommerce - wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, checked

I'm a bit new to wordpress and would like to have some advise. I try to add a optional field to the card which rounds the card total. I would like that it doesnt round the card total when it isnt checked.. So this is my
[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B9VW.jpg)
and i used this code for it:

@functios.php

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() {

    global $woocommerce;

    $totalprice = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
    $rounded = ceil($totalprice);
    $donation = $rounded-$totalprice;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Donatie', 'woocommerce'),$donation);

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

and this @cart-totals.php

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
    <tr class="fee">
        <th><input type="checkbox"><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
        <td data-title="<?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So who can tell me where I can add some function that will only rounds my cart total when the donation option is checked?

Comment: Try this : https://sarkware.com/woocommerce-add-donation-box-checkout-page/

Comment: Im not looking for a plugin where you can add a custom donation.. but thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am not fully understand what you want to do. But it sound need to have this sentence in your option for checking it is checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="your-option-name" value="1" <?php checked(1, get_option('your-option-name'), true); ?> />
```

You can find the definition of [Function Reference/checked](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked).

After that, add the if case for checking if it is checked. Like below

```
// 1 is the value of the checkbox that you defined.
if(get_option("your-option-name") == 1){
    <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
        <tr class="fee">
            <th><input type="checkbox"><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
}
```

Here is the link that I established the option previously.
[Building Your Own Social Sharing Plugin for WordPress](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-own-social-sharing-plugin-for-wordpress/)

Hope it can help you.